# Using a variable with Jekyll's contain operator

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
{% if file.basename contains {{basename}} %}
```

All the examples I have seen explicitly use a value, like this:

```
{% if file.basename contains 'image' %}
```

If it matters, I'm trying to loop through `site.static_files` and only capture the files whose basename matches a variable passed in through an include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the variable directly as an expression:

```
{% if file.basename contains basename %}
```

The `{{` syntax is only used to print expressions from markup.